# How to display values from database in real time with apollo client 3 and react js?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, graphql, apollo-client

How to display values from database in real time without refreshing the webpage ?

How to update data with apollo client 3, for example, a user adds a category, how to make this category appear to all other pages?

This function lists all the categories from the database:

```
async  componentDidMount() {
setInterval(async()=>{
  
  await client.query({
    query: LISTER_CATEGORIE 
  },   
  )
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, categories: response.data.listerCategorie });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));


},3000)
}
```

This is the client:

```
  export const client = new ApolloClient({
      link: ApolloLink.from([
        onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) => console.log(`[GraphQL error]:
 Message: ${message},
 Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`));
    if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);}),
    new createUploadLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql'})
    ]),
      cache: new InMemoryCache({ typePolicies: {
        Query: {
          fields: {
            categorie(existingData, { args, toReference }) {
              return existingData || 
                toReference({ __typename: 'Categorie', id: args.id });
            },
          .............
```

And this function adds a category:

```
async  ajouterCategorie() {
await client.mutate({
  mutation: AJOUTER_CATEGORIE,
  variables: {
    titre: this.state.newCategorie.titre,
    presentation: this.state.newCategorie.presentation,
    image: '',
    dateCreation: new Date(),
    file: this.state.file,
    cours: []
  }, refetchQueries: [
    { query: LISTER_CATEGORIE }
  ], 
})
  .then((response) => {
    
    this.props.add(response.data.ajouterCategorie)
    this.pushNotify("Catégorie Ajouté avec succès", 'success', "Ajout Categorie")
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
this.handleClose()
}
```

I used ComponentDidUpadate but it not worked either.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From what I can see, this has been setup to behave the way expected, are you seeing any errors in your console log and are these changes seen when manually querying GQL? I'd also recommend creating an error handler with a Promise and an example can be found on this dev doc: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/refetching/#handling-refetch-errors